# Why can't I enter text into a textarea control that is inside of the highcharts-container div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

When I put a textarea inside of the highcharts-container div, I am unable to click into textarea and enter text. Here is a fiddle to show the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/0oh0zfu9/

```
$('.highcharts-container').append();
```

I do not have this problem when I place the div outside of that div. I really want to be able to have the div inside of the highcharts-container div for some positioning reasons.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Try using an outer container that holds both the chart container and the textarea. Likely running into conflicts with event handlers bound to chart container

Comment: move it outside `.highcharts-container` as it handles mouse click events

Comment: Why you add the textarea into highcharts-container? Better is wrap the chart into div and push textarea in separate object. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/urkne9fe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `autofocus` attribute to the textarea: http://jsfiddle.net/0oh0zfu9/1/

**changed JS**

```
$('.highcharts-container').append(
    /* ... */
    '<textarea style="border-color: #66afe9; box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #66afe9;" class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="Comment" autofocus></textarea>'
    /* ... */
);
```

But as *[@Trix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714740/why-cant-i-enter-text-into-a-textarea-control-that-is-inside-of-the-highcharts#comment-62903167)* pointed out, it is generally not advised to add such elements to the highchart container.